# How to update value of dictionary in iOS Swift?

Tags: swift, dictionary

```
var request: [String: Any] = [

    "Token": "Token",
    "Request": [
        "CityID": "CityID",
        "Filters": [
            "IsRecommendedOnly": "0",
            "IsShowRooms": "0"
        ]
    ]
]
//
print(request)
```

Console output:

```
["Token": "Token", "Request": ["CityID": "CityID", "Filters": ["IsRecommendedOnly": "0", "IsShowRooms": "0"]]]
```

Here I want to update value of **"IsShowRooms"** key from value **"0"** to value **"1"**, I was tried different steps but I am unable to do so, can anyone help me out in this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the value by typecasting Any to its type and store its value back

```
if var requestVal = request["Request"] as? [String: Any], var filters = requestVal["Filters"] as? [String: String] {
    filters["IsShowRooms"] = "1"
    requestVal["Filters"] = filters
    request["Request"] = requestVal
}
```

Output

> ["Token": "Token", "Request": ["CityID": "CityID", "Filters": ["IsRecommendedOnly": "0", "IsShowRooms": "1"]]]

OR

Instead of storing values in Dictionary create a struct. It will be easier to update its properties

Answer (score 1):

You can do this following way.(**Dictionary in swift is treated as value type**)

```
if var reqObj = request["Request"] as? [String: Any] {

  if var obj = reqObj["Filters"] as? [String: Any] {

    obj["IsShowRooms"] = "1"
    reqObj["Filters"] = obj
  }
  request["Request"] = reqObj
}
print(request)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
["Request": ["CityID": "CityID", "Filters": ["IsShowRooms": "1", "IsRecommendedOnly": "0"]], "Token": "Token"]
```

Comment: It doesn't change IsShowRooms's value to 1. It adds a new IsShowRooms with value 1

Comment: agree with comment of @RajeshKumar R